# Why does this code have a missing return statement error?

Tags: java

If I change the else if portion of this code to an else statement it runs without any problems so I get how to make it run. What I'm a little confused about is why I get a missing return statement error when it is in its current form. My return is dependent on the value of the boolean variable of negative. I covered the true and false states, isn't that good enough to cover everything?

Or is it that I always have to have a return statement within an else or to add a meaningless return true to the bottom of my function for the compiler to accept my code as covering every case?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
      if (!negative) {
        return (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0);
      }
      else if (negative) {
        return (a < 0 && b < 0);
      }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: if `!negative` is `false`, isn't `negative` `true`?  Why would you write that?  I suppose you could complain that the compiler should be able to figure that out for you, but it obviously doesn't.  And why should it?  Do you know how complicated it would be for the compiler to try and figure out if your weird code really could have been just written as an if-else?

Comment: You don't need an `if`: `return (negative && (a < 0 && b < 0)) || (!negative && ((a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0)));`

Comment: @Jared - Exactly. The compiler can't always confirm that all possibilities have been considered, but it can easily determine this if you use an else block or have a return after the if/elses. Remember, the boolean expressions in an if statement aren't always as simple and straight forward as they are in your example.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - it would take me over a minute to figure out what that means... although it seems that doesn't bother some people. I like to write code that is instantly readable to anyone.

Comment: @jahroy But of course, it's a "write-only" statement :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the compiler sees `else if` without an `else` or a trailing return statement, it cannot be certain that all control paths will lead to a valid return statement.

The compiler can be smart at times, but it can't be smart in this situation (nor should it be).

This behavior is helpful in your example: there's absolutely no reason for you to use an `else if` in this situation. A simple `else` is easier to read, more concise, and less error prone.

An `else` is very expressive in this case. It means "*the opposite of the if clause*" which will still be the case if the code changes in the future.

Your current code would be more likely to contain and/or introduce a bug if the compiler allowed it.

Here's how I would rewrite the method body:

```
if (negative) {
    return (a < 0 && b < 0);
}
else {
    return (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0);
}
```

In general you should prefer `if (negative)` over `if (!negative)` unless there's a compelling reason (ie readability) to do otherwise.

Also, a lot of people (including myself) try to put the most simple clause first in an *if/else* statement. Making your code easy to read is a good thing.

Check out StephenC's answer for a technical explanation and more background about why the compiler behaves this way.

Comment: The compiler is not allowed to be smart about this.  See my Answer.

Comment: @StephenC - Perhaps I chose my words poorly. I meant that the compiler can often make _smart_ decisions, but it can't be smart in this situation. As you've pointed it, it needs to follow specific rules that ensure a valid return statement will be executed.

Answer (score 4):

Other questions have explained what the error message means from an intuitive perspective.  However the *"The compiler is smart, but not perfect!"* comment is missing the point.

In fact, the Java compiler is calling your example an error because the Java Language Specification *requires* it to call it an error.  The Java compiler is **not permitted to be "smart" about this**.

---

Here is what the JLS (for Java 7<sup>1</sup>) actually says, and how it applies to a simplified version of the incorrect example, and then a corrected version.

> *"If a method is declared to have a return type, then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally ([JLS 14.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1)).   In other words, a method with a return type must return only by using a return statement that provides a value return; it is not allowed to "drop off the end of its body". "* - [JLS 8.4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7)

(Read [JLS 14.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1) for the definition of "normal completion" ...)

And the rules for deciding whether a "normal" completion is possible are the reachability rules in [JLS 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21).  And they say:

> 1. *"An if-then statement can complete normally iff it is reachable."*
> 2. *"An if-then-else statement can complete normally iff the then-statement can complete normally or the else-statement can complete normally."*
> 3. *"A break, continue, return, or throw statement cannot complete normally."*

(Where 'iff' means "if and only if" ...)

Consider a simplified version of the example:

```
   public int test(boolean a) {
      if (a) {
        return 1;
      }
      else if (!a) {
        return 0;
      }
   }
```

In this example, the else-statement is an if-then which can complete normally by rule #1.  Therefore, by rule #2, the if-then-else statement can also complete normally.  But that is a compilation error, because [JLS 8.4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7) says that a method with a return type *cannot* complete normally.

But if you change the example to this ...

```
  public int test(boolean a) {
      if (a) {
        return 1;
      }
      else {
        return 0;
      }
  }
```

Now by rule #3, both the if-statement and the else-statement cannot complete normally.  So by rule #2, the entire if-then-else cannot complete normally.  That is what it required by [JLS 8.4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7) ... therefore no compilation error.

<sup>1 - The Java 8 JLS will say essentially the same thing, though the section numbers may be different ...</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but don't understand the way you explain the example. Are you saying the 1st example is valid and the 2nd example is not? That's how I read it and that doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: No.  I am saying that the first example is not valid Java, and the second one is.  The requirement is that a method body for a method with a return type *cannot* complete normally.  If it can, then that is a compilation error.  (Updated Answer to clarify ...)

Comment: OK. That's what I thought, but I was having a hard time finding that meaning in your words. I think it would be a big help to define "_completing normally_" as "_completing without an explicit return statement with a valid return type_". As usual the language in the spec isn't immediately intuitive (in my opinion).

Comment: @jahroy - 1) I made a mistake.  The correct terminology is "complete normally" not "return normally".  2)  The terminology comes from the JLS, and it is (IMO) inadvisable to change the terminology when talking about what a specification says.  3) Yes, the words to may be hard to understand ... but if I can do it, so can you :-)

Answer (score 3):

`if` => `else if` => where is the `else` condition?

For a return statement, **all branches (conditions) must be handled.**

You could do:

```
if (!negative)
  return (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0);
return (a < 0 && b < 0);
```

or:

```
if (!negative)
  return (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0)
else
  return (a < 0 && b < 0);
```

or (my preferred way):

```
return negative ? (a < 0 && b < 0) : (a < 0 && b > 0 || a > 0 && b < 0)
```

However, I'd recommend to avoid the negative condition, it's harder for the human brain in complex scenario. Even some Java IDEs like IntelliJ helps to find those patterns to fix them.
You'd end up with:

```
if (negative)
      return (a < 0 && b < 0);
else
      return (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0);
```

Comment: Boy are those suggestions hard to read... I'd just keep it simple with an `if/else`.

Comment: it's just a matter of taste

Comment: It doesn't look as bad now that I'm not using my phone ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you already know that the second if is redundant.

`if (negative)` is interpreted context-free, which means that the compiler ignores that `if(!negative)` has already been handled.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need "if (negative) {}" in the "else" brace

Comment: Not only is it not necessary, it increases the chances of introducing a bug mightily.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a return in all your branches.

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  if (!negative) {
    return (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0);
  }
  else if (negative) {
    return (a < 0 && b < 0);
  }
}
```

The method above logically has a return in all branches, but technically it does not. We like the Java compiler to be fast, therefore it is undesirable to have a Java compiler analyzing semantically the code.

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  if (!negative) {
    return (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0);
  }
  else {
    return (a < 0 && b < 0);
  }
}
```

The method above has a return in all the branches.

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  if (!negative) {
    return (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0);
  }
  return (a < 0 && b < 0);
}
```

However, as you can see above, you do not even need the else, because if the code ever reaches the second return, then negative is certainly false, as if it was true, the first return would end the algorithm.

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  return ((negative) && (a < 0 && b < 0)) || ((!negative)  && (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0));
}
```

The method above is a one-liner.

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  return ((negative) && (a < 0 && b < 0)) || ((!negative)  && ((a < 0) == (b > 0)));
}
```

The method above uses the fact that in the second case the positivity of `a` is equal with the negativity of `b`.