# Why eclipse is saying that my method doesn't return a valid result?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, return

I've been doing this code in java for a Sudoku game since a while and I don't know what's wrong, Maybe is the "if" or de "For", but the IDE says that my method doesn't return a booelean type.

```
// check if the number has already been used in the columns
private boolean checkColumns(int x, int y, int value) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (this.gridPlayer[j][y].getValue() == value) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    }
// Check if the number has already been used in the lines
private boolean checkLines(int x, int y, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (this.gridPlayer[x][i].getValue() == value) return false;
         else return true;
    }
    }

// Check if the number has already been used and the subGrid
private boolean checkSubGrid(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
            if (this.gridPlayer[x][y].getValueOfSubGrid(x, y) == this.gridPlayer[i][j].getValueOfSubGrid(i, j)) {
                if (this.gridPlayer[x][y].getValue() == this.gridPlayer[i][j].getValue()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (this.gridPlayer[x][y].getValueOfSubGrid(x, y) != this.gridPlayer[i][j].getValueOfSubGrid(i,
                    j)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should happen if the `else if` check returns false?

Comment: Which method does the compiler complain about?

Comment: Unless you're playing 10-square sudoku, I suggest you might mean `i < 9` and `j < 9`.

Comment: Which method ? You posted 3.

Comment: @c0der all 3 of them.

Comment: Are you sure the logic of these loops is right? In most cases you return a value no matter what, making the loop a single iteration, making a loop unnecessary. In any case, `checkSubGrid` doesn't handle all cases, and the logic for looking for returns isn't terribly smart anyway, and you'll want returns outside of the `for` loops.

Comment: @DrewKennedy i would use the value to check in another method if is ok or no to put that value in a cell of the Sudoku Game

Comment: @c0der all three seems to show the same error

Comment: Side note: consider `{` and `}` around **all** blocks, it makes life easier for you and others who may need to amend the code in future. It also prevents unnecessary bugs where code is accidentally outside a block and could be in another block. In your first two methods, just `return true` outside of the for loops, no need for `else`.

Comment: @DaveNewton i can't not see how can i return outside of the for, since i need to check all the array things

Comment: I think you mean : `private boolean checkColumns(int y, int value) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (this.gridPlayer[j][y].getValue() == value) return true;
    }
         return false; //no match found
    }`

Comment: @josericardo Right now you're checking a single item, so it can't be any worse. The return outside the loop is so you don't get the compile error, regardless of any other logic (which as I said, is not correct as written).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is assuming that it is not 100% sure that the return statement from within 
your "for" loops will be called so it is seeing a path where your methods do not return any values even though they declare they do.

You need to have some return value outside of your loops, even if you are sure this will never happen i.e.

```
private boolean checkLines(int x, int y, int value) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (this.gridPlayer[x][i].getValue() == value) return false;
     else return true;
  }
 return false; //even if you think it will never be run it is necessary 
}
```

Comment: This `for` loop is executed once only. I do not think that is what you mean. Also `int y` is never used

Comment: @c0der that is exactly what I mean. The compiler does not assume that the for loop is always run even when you know it is. I dont care if int y us never used, I just enhanced the OP method to show him where was the problem

Comment: What is the use of a `for` loop that is executed once ? Clearly it does not check the whole line.

Comment: I think the intent was to show the need for the `return`, not to fix the original flawed logic.

Comment: @c0der Exactly what Dave Newton says. I answered the question and shown that IDE(actually java compiler) is not the problem, but there theoretically not every path returns a value

Comment: @maslan Well, in `checklines` a return value is guaranteed in the `for` loop for the exact code given. The issue isn't that it isn't guaranteed to return a value, because here it is. The issue is in the JLS as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/22739223/438992 and the JLS itself.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome,
in your `checkSubGrid()` method you need to return a value if the runtime dont enter in the last `else if`:
`else if (this.gridPlayer[x][y]...) {`

If the method is not `void`, you need to put a return.

```
 if(a > 1) {
   return a;
 } else {
   return b;
 }
```

In this case above we have a `if - else` statement, the method will **always** return true or false(or have a exception).

```
 if(a > 1) {
   return a;
 } else if(a == 0) {
   return b;
 }
```

In other hand, the method can or can not enter in the second `if`, them you have no returns. You are not making sure that the compiler will have a return.

You can solve this putting a default return, or putting a else statement.

```
 if(a > 1) {
   return a;
 } else if(a == 0) {
   return b;
 } else {
   return null;
 }
```

Or

```
 if(a > 1) {
   return a;
 } else if(a == 0) {
   return b;
 }
 return null;
```

Comment: Returning `null` where return value is of type `boolean` is not valid (compilation error)

Comment: And the compiler doesn't do anything complicated to ensure a method has a return, e.g., in the OP's `checkColumns` it's guaranteed to return a boolean, right? It still emits the warning because reasons.

Comment: Yes @DaveNewton, but if the compiler do not enter in the `for`, there is no return eighter. Not sure what case can not enter inside `for` but ok :)